# Returning non-editable MathType equations to their original size

Tags: windows-8.1, macros, microsoft-word-2013, pictures, mathtype

I have a `Word` document with about 200 pages and `.docx` format. There are many `MathType` formulas in it. After many edit on my file, most of the formulas converted to picture. I did [this](http://www.dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/tsn/tsn103.htm) but it doesn't work for me. Worst of all, the size of converted equations changed, some became larger and some became smaller. I can reset the size manually by right clicking on the picture, unchecking `look aspect ratio` and setting `Scale Height` and `Scale Width` to 100 but worst of all of all again, I can't reset the size of the pictures using a `macro` with setting `ScaleHeight` and `ScaleWidth` to 100. Here is my code

```
Sub ScaleSelectedInlineShapes()
    Dim shape As InlineShape
    For Each shape In Selection.InlineShapes
        With shape
            .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
            .ScaleHeight = 100
            .ScaleWidth = 100
        End With
    Next shape
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

MathType has a command included with its macros that are installed as an add-in to Word. This command, *Convert Equations*, is included on the MathType tab in Word for Windows, and the MathType menu in Word 2011 for Mac (and is mentioned in TSN 103 to which you linked in your original question). The Convert Equations command will reformat the equations to 100x100%. Just leave the dialog options set to the defaults and run it.

What Convert Equations will *not* do is resize an equation that was improperly sized to begin with. As an example, consider a document in which the text is set to 10pt, but the MathType equation is too large to fit so the author drags a corner and resizes the equation. Running Convert Equations will resize all the equations to 100x100% of *their original size*, without regard to what the dragged size is. If you have equations that you have dragged to resize, there's nothing MathType can do to restore them to 100x100% of the size you want, because it has no way to know what that size is.